# Trouble with jQuery Nivo Slider and Prestashop 1.5

Tags: jquery, prestashop, nivo-slider

I have some trouble with the jQuery implementation in Prestashop 1.5. When I install a NivoSlider module, it works at first, but as soon as I rehook it elsewhere it all breaks and the NivoSlider (as well as the product slider) stops working.

Could anyone can point me in the right direction?

Here's the link: http://daniel-klose.com/prestatest

I am also getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider' in line 195`.

Comment: Does not look like your nevoslider.js file is actually being loaded. Make sure your hook is right. `TypeError: $("#slider").nivoSlider is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that nivoSlider library (ex. jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js) loaded on page